# ¿Cómo hacer una galería de imagenes y crear un modal con cada una?

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagen, modal

Estoy haciendo una web en la que quiero hacer una galería y quiero que este javascript me sirva para crear un pop up por imagen. Pero le cambio el nombre del id a #open2 #close2 #modal_container2 y no me funciona. ¿Alguien sabe que puede ser? La pregunta no es como hacer la galería, si no cómo hacer que el modal me sirva para cada foto. Creo que el problema está en

> addEventListener('click'

Como podéis comprobar estoy intentando hacer esto para las siguientes imágenes pero no me está funcionando. No se si al ponerlo así me estoy explicando un poco mejor.

```js
const open2 = document.getElementById('open2');
const modal_container2 = document.getElementById('modal_container2');
const close2 = document.getElementById('close2');

open.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal_container2.classList.add('show2');
});

close.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal_container2.classList.remove('show2');
});
```

```css
  .modal-container2 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.show2 {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.centrate {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

```html
<li class="grid-item animacion wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
  <a href="#" id="open2">
    <div class="portfolio-img bg-extra-dark-gray"><img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/avatar-man-icon-profile-placeholder-260nw-1229859850.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus elementum condimentum ligula, sit amet consectetur sapien. Sed porta nunc id dapibus blandit."
      /></div>
  </a>
  <span class="portfolio-item-title">Lorem ipsum.</span>
</li>


<div class="modal-container2" id="modal_container2">
  <div class="centrate">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/avatar-man-icon-profile-placeholder-260nw-1229859850.jpg" />
    <p style="color: aliceblue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus elementum condimentum ligula, sit amet consectetur sapien. Sed porta nunc id dapibus blandit.</p>
    <button id="close2" href="#">Cerrar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cuando le das click a la imagen aparece el modal?, o sea aparece la imagen con el texto debajo y demas

Comment: Sí, el problema está cuando quieres hacer una galería de imagenes y que esto funcione para cada imagen y que el pop up cambie en función de la imagen

Comment: Creo que ya vi si agregas otra imagen no funciona como la primera

Comment: He editado la pregunta y creo que ahora se entiende mejor

Comment: @Mar: Bien hecho, tan solo recuerda pulsar el botón **Ordenar** cuando lo pongas en un snippet para que no se muestren tantos espacios que dificultan la lectura

Comment: @Mar: En el segundo caso da un error de javascript que dice que `open.addEventListener` no es una función, porque en el segundo caso debe ser `open2` y no `open`

Comment: Ya te arregle el problema en un momento subo la respuesta @Mar y te explico

Comment: Sí! Ya lo he visto. Mil gracias llevaba horas con el código y no lo veía

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El en HTML se agregó un **div (gallery)** que va a contener todas las imágenes o sea los `ul` con sus `li` como también añadí sus respectivas clases (Cambie los IDs por clases) que me ayudaran a gestionarlo el `js`.

***HTML***

```
<div class="gallery">
        <ul class="thumbItems">
            <li data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                <a href="#" id="open">
                    <div class="portfolio-img bg-extra-dark-gray"><img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/avatar-man-icon-profile-placeholder-260nw-1229859850.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus elementum condimentum ligula, sit amet consectetur sapien. Sed porta nunc id dapibus blandit."/></div>
                </a>    
                    <span class="portfolio-item-title">Lorem ipsum.</span>
            </li>
            <li data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                <a href="#" id="open">
                    <div class="portfolio-img bg-extra-dark-gray"><img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/avatar-man-icon-profile-placeholder-260nw-1229859850.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus elementum condimentum ligula, sit amet consectetur sapien. Sed porta nunc id dapibus blandit."/></div>
                </a>    
                    <span class="portfolio-item-title">Lorem ipsum.</span>
            </li>
        </ul> 
        <div class="modal-container" id="modal_container">
            <div class="centrate">
              <img title="modal" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/avatar-man-icon-profile-placeholder-260nw-1229859850.jpg" />
              <p style="color: aliceblue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus elementum condimentum ligula, sit amet consectetur sapien. Sed porta nunc id dapibus blandit.</p>
              <button id="close" href="#">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
          </div>  
    </div>
```

***JavaScript***

Si vez solo capture la clase de `gallery` que es el div que contiene las imágenes y utilice `querySelectorAll` porque son clases y no getElementById.

Luego como es un `querySelectorAll` este devuelve un objeto similar a una matriz denominado lista de nodos. Luego esa lista de nodos la recorro con un `forEach` y capturo el evento **click** de cada imagen.

***querySelector:***

> Retorna el primer elemento que cumpla con el criterio dado. Puede ser
> invocada sobre el document o sobre algún elemento. En caso de usarse
> sobre un elemento, las búsqueda se limita a los hijos de ese elemento.
> Si la búsqueda no encuentra nada, retorna null.

***querySelectorAll:***

> Retorna todos los elementos que cumplan con el criterio dado. Al igual
> que querySelector puede ser invocada sobre el document o sobre algún
> elemento. Siempre retorna un NodeList, el cual no es una array con
> todas las de la ley (map, reduce, indexOf, etc), pero pude convertirse
> en uno, con facilidad.

```
const gallery = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbItems")
    const close = document.getElementById('close');

        gallery.forEach((item) => {
            item.addEventListener("click", function() {
                modal_container.classList.add('show');
            });
        })

    close.addEventListener('click', () => {
        modal_container.classList.remove('show');
    });
```

**CSS** (Se quedo igual)

```
 .modal-container{
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            position: fixed;
            pointer-events: none;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: 2;
            vertical-align: middle;
            }  

        .show{
            pointer-events: auto;
            opacity: 1;
            z-index: 2;
        }
           
        .centrate{
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%; left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
```

Comment: Esto es definitivamente mucho más sencillo de cómo lo estaba haciendo. Gracias

Comment: Qué bueno, me alegro de haberte ayudado.

Comment: También puedes dar a respuesta útil, la flechita hacia arriba. :D